Client script not executing on invoice record
I have created simple client script and deployed on both invoice and item fulfillment record. The script is execution on item fulfillment, I can see alert. But same script is not execution on invoice.
Please advice!
  /**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
 define(['N/record', 'N/ui/dialog'],
    function(record,dialog) {
        function saveRecord(context) {
            alert("saverecord executing");
            log.debug("saverecord");
            }
        function pageInit(context) {
             alert("pageinit");
            log.debug("pageinit");
       
        }
        return {
            saveRecord: saveRecord,
            pageInit:pageInit
    };
}

);

Try deleting the existing deployment and re-creating one for the Invoice. Also make sure that 'All Roles' and 'All Employees' checkboxes are checked on the deployment record.
Also use a try-catch block for your code. In the catch section you can use logger to check for errors, if any.
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/record', 'N/ui/dialog'], function (record, dialog) {
    
    function saveRecord(context) {
        try {
            alert("saverecord executing");
            log.debug("saverecord");
        } catch (e) {
            log.debug('Error: ', e.message);
        }
    }
    function pageInit(context) {
        try {
            alert("pageinit");
            log.debug("pageinit");
        } catch (e) {
            log.debug('Error: ', e.message);
        }
    }
    return {
        saveRecord: saveRecord,
        pageInit: pageInit
    };
})


I did this but still same problem. Actually on invoice record, there are 22 client scripts deployed, when I changed my script priority in scripted records, my script executes. But the problem is by this other client scripts such may not execute.

Only the 10 first client script will be executed, try to merge the clients scripts together
